# merge two columns from two different dataframes in conditions, python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

input:

```
df1:
name, msg_time, age
adam,22-00-11, Nan
susam,23-00-14,Nan

df2:
name, age
adam, 23
```

i want to add `msg_time` from `df1` to `df['age']` for specific `name`

output:

df2:

```
name, age
adam, 23,22-00-11
```

my code:

```
df2=df2.assign(age=lambda x: x.age +','+df1.msg_time)
```

my problem is, that i am receiving :

```
df2:
name, age
adam, 23,22-00-11,22-00-11,22-00-11,22-00-11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do it using [`series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and converting to string before concatenating them using `astype(str)`:

```
df2.age=df2.age.astype(str)+','+df2.name.map(df1.set_index('name')['msg_time']).astype(str)
print(df2)
```

---

```
   name          age
0  adam  23,22-00-11
```

Answer (score 2):

You could [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on `name` and `join` the fields of interest separated by `,`:

```
(df1.merge(df2, on='name')
    .set_index('name')[['age_y', 'msg_time']]
    .astype(str)
    .apply(','.join, axis=1)
    .rename('age')
    .reset_index())
```

---

```
   name          age
0  adam  23,22-00-11
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using `combine_first`

```
df2.set_index('name').combine_first(df1.set_index('name')).dropna().astype(str).apply(' '.join,1).to_frame('age')
                age
name               
adam  23.0 22-00-11
```